# why does this socket program take different ports every time i connect to it

Tags: java, sockets, port

Server side program

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
                        serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Just connected to "
                        + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                DataInputStream in =
                    new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                DataOutputStream out =
                    new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
                        + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
                server.close();
            }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
            {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try
        {
            Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
            t.start();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client side program

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String serverName = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                    + " on port " + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                    + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in =
                new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
            client.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And any file send and recieved if possible.
I tried a lot but I couldn't figure out why different ports are used and file operations.

Answer (score 3):

> why does this socket program take different ports every time i connect
>   to it

That's what the OS does when you connect an unbound socket. It picks some available source port (called "*ephemeral port*") and uses it. If you want to ensure it picks a certain port you need to [`bind`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) the socket.

Comment: can u please help me with binding the port and IP Address
i need to send files as well as data objects i coudnt figure it out my self....
thanks in advance!!..